# EntityType and many to many with extra field relation presented as dropdown (select)

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I created a form like that

```php
$builder->add('employees', EntityType::class, [
    'class'         => ActivityEmployee::class,
    'choice_label'  => function (ActivityEmployee $employee) {
        return sprintf('%s %s', $employee->getEmployee()->getName(), $employee->getEmployee()->getLastName());
    },
    'multiple'      => true,
])
```

As a result it presents already existing data fine. It shows me all employees with relation to edited activity.

However as `choices` there should be all employess to choose (`employee` entity) and as selected `data` only employess in activityEmployee relation like right now.

I tried to add a `query_builder` option to provide lists of all employess, but I can only use `EntityRepository` which means `ActivityEmployeesRepository` not `EmployeesRepository` per se.

A can't figure out how to implement it. Basically such relation can be done by `CollectionType` of custom `activityEmployeeType` but I'd like to use multi-select for selecting employees.

I can use another approach to not mapping my employees field to entity like that

```
$currentEmployees = [];
foreach ($activity->getEmployees() as $activityEmployee) {
    $currentEmployees[] = $activityEmployee->getEmployee();
}
$builder->add('employees', EntityType::class, [
    'class'        => Employee::class,
    'choice_label' => function (Employee $employee) {
        return sprintf('%s %s', $employee->getName(), $employee->getLastName());
    },
    'mapped'       => false,
    'multiple'     => true,
    'data'         => $currentEmployees,
]);
```

It works fine, but I need to deal with updating relation by myself. Which is ok, however I wonder how to achieve such thing in first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation details matter. As far as I can understand you have the following entities:

```
Activity (entity)
  - employees (OneToMany -> ActivityEmployee)
ActivityEmployee (entity)
  - activity (ManyToOne -> Activity)
  - employee (ManyToOne -> Employee)
Employee (entity)
  - activities (OneToMany -> ActivityEmployee) - this one might be missing, actually.
```

Now you apparently don't hide *any* implementation details. Meaning, your `Activity::getEmployees()` returns `[]ActivityEmployee`.

I would have done it like this:

```
class Activity {
   /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ActivityEmployee::class) */
   private $activityEmployees;

   /** @return Employee[] */
   public function getEmployees() :Collection {
       return $this->activityEmployees->map(function(ActivityEmployee $ae) {
             return $ae->getEmployee();
       });
   }

   public function addEmployee(Employee $employee) {
       // check, if the employee is already registered, add only then!
       if(!$this->getEmployees()->contains($employee)) {
           $this->activityEmployees->add(new ActivityEmployee($this, $employee));
       }
   }
   public function removeEmployee(Employee $employee) {
       foreach($this->activityEmployees as $activityEmployee) {
           if($activityEmployee->getEmployee() === $employee) {
                $this->activityEmployees->removeElement($activityEmployee);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

This way, you hide away how `Activity` handles the employees and to the outside world (and specifically the PropertyAccessor, that the form component uses) it appears as if `Activity` has a property `employees` which are actually `Employee[]`.

If you implement it like this, your first form should actually just work (obviously exchanging ActivityEmployee for Employee) - under the assumption that I didn't make some major mistake. Of course I would also add methods like `getActivityEmployees` when I would actually specificially need the relation objects.

This whole thing certainly is less beautiful if your many-to-many can contain duplicates.

**IF** your ActivityEmployee actually has NO other properties besides `activity` and `employee`, you could obviously replace the whole thing with a `@ORM\ManyToMany` and just work with `Employee[]` instead of the `ActivityEmployee[]`. However, I assume you have some additional columns like `created` or something.

Comment: Thank you. Your `getEmployess` method was a key to do that. I wasn't thinking that way. It's nice to broaden the mindset.

My _extra field_ in that relation is the order of selected options by user. I need to save which employee was selected first, second and so on. I even tried to achieve that somehow using form events, but I don't think that it would be ever possible. I ended up with your solution and I set up order later in controller/service basing on array from http request.